# Laplacian pyramids in computer vision

Tags: computer-vision

What are the properties of laplacian pyramids that make them useful. What is the benefit of the expand operator. Couldn't we just do a gaussian smoothing appropriate for every scale rather than a reduce and expand

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: I think this can be answered by reading a few papers, articles and lectures about Laplacian pyramids and their applications. Your question is too broad No one will write a scientific essay about that to answer your question.

Comment: The Laplacian Pyramid is a representation of image [scale space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space). I agree that this question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a newbie to both stack overflow and computer vision. So sorry about being very vague and broad any my question. The wiki page on scale space is exactly what I am looking for 